# android detect gps location every after 10 mins

Tags: android, gps

Android: i am using gps check box in my application, which user check this we use gps location of the user.

Now i have to make change if user check this checkbox we use gps location and if user remain this box checked then we have to detect user location every after 10 mins and if location is different we have to prompt user that location is change and if user want to use new location.

any idea how appy listner which get fire every after 10 min and get stop after detecting location ? any good idea to implement it just want you guys idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing a service that runs on the background which can make a call once in every 10 mins and update the application about its changes

Comment: However if you feel you can update the user only if the location changes on the device you can use LocationListener interface

Comment: how can i have service started from one activity and accessible in all activities ?

Comment: In that case you need to send a broadcast from your service and enable your application to receive that broadcast

Answer (score 0):

u can define your customized minimum time between two location updates
its here
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,mintime, 0, locationListener);
u can provide your own mintime